# How to let user upload files to S3 bucket, but not overwrite or delete?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have the following IAM policy for a user

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1395161912000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "list",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The goal is to let the user upload files to the bucket, but not overwrite or delete. It's for backup. I started out with `ListBucket` and `PutObject`, but added `*` as it didn't work. Not even `*` lets the user upload files, just getting `Access Denied`.

When I try the Simulator, it returns `Denied - Implicitly denied (no matching statements found).` for `ListBucket`, which seems odd since I've implicitly allowed that.

I've tried both Cyberduck and 3Hub as S3 clients.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When crafting [Amazon IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) policies for [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), you need to be aware of the difference between [Operations on the Service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPServiceOps.html) (e.g. [ListAllMyBuckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListAllMyBuckets.html)), [Operations on Buckets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPBucketsOps.html) (e.g. [ListBucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListBucket.html)) and [Operations on Objects](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPObjectsOps.html) (e.g. [GetObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPGetObject.html)).

In particular, the `Resource` specification of your policy needs to address the appropriate target entities according to the following patterns (see e.g. the various [Example Policies for Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html#ExamplePolicies_S3)):

- Operations on Service - `arn:aws:s3:::*`
- Operations on Buckets - `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>`
- Operations on Objects - `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/<object>`

### Solution

You are encountering `Access Denied`, because you've specified a bucket level resource for `PutObject`, which requires an object level resource specification like `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*` - accordingly, the following policy should cover your sample use case:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked flawlessly. Thank you! So `sid` is not required?

Comment: According to [Sid](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Sid), it is _is an optional identifier that you provide for the policy statement_, which _must be unique within a policy_. Given it seems to work fine w/o (but see below), I tend to remove it here for brevity and when versionizing policies, but do not bother when generating policies automatically for example - however, as per the subsequent **Note**: _Some AWS services (for example, Amazon SQS or Amazon SNS) might require this element [...]_.

Comment: OP says they want "to let the user upload files to the bucket, but not overwrite or delete", but this policy grants `PutObject`, which allows overriding objects, no?  I think there's no way to separate that out.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov - the S3 ´PutObject´ action indeed implies overwriting, it's simply how S3 works by default. If you need protection against accidental deletion, you might want to look into [Using versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) _to preserve, retrieve, and restore every version of every object stored in your Amazon S3 bucket._ - this allows you to _easily recover from both unintended user actions and application failures_.

Comment: Yes, versioning gives you the ability to recover objects that have been overwritten (but you have to discover that they have been, and then go do that).  Anyways, -1 because it doesn't provide an accurate answer to the question.

Comment: See also: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-managing.html